# Logic App Sharepoint File Name Wrong When Pulling File

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to access a file from Sharepoint from my Azure Logic App. I am using the Sharepoint connector "When a file is created or modified in a folder". The file is accessed by the connector but it the properties the file name is given as "Z2lnYWJpdF92b3VjaGVycy5jc3Y=" rather than the actual file name "mydata.csv". Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

It will be in a base64 format so you need to use base64tostring in compose connector i.e.. base64ToString(< FileName >)

Here is the screenshot for your reference
[image]